# python, when use writestr there is a text newline issue

Tags: python, zip, stringio

I need your help~
I have a LF problem when I use 'wirtestr'. 
the text have been written into zip well 
but It comes in one line without line breaks. 
Only I could find the delimiter which looks like square has circle in the middle of it, maybe hex code for newline.
If anyone knows about this problem please help!

```
         fp = StringIO(line)
         value = fp.getvalue()
         filename1 = 'D:/re/m/11.txt'
         filename2 = 'D:/re/m/dd.zip'
         archive = zipfile.ZipFile(filename2, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
         finfo   = zipfile.ZipInfo(filename1)
         archive.writestr(finfo, value)
```

Comment: Are you viewing the file in notepad in Windows?

Comment: yes, I am. I have to zip txt files(notepad)

Comment: Notepad doesn't respect normal line endings. If you use any other (decent) text editor you might find the endings look OK.

Comment: yes! But when I do like open('d:/dd.txt', 'w') as f: the text comes out fine by notepadTT

Comment: This works because python puts the windows line ending in that notepad expects.  Use this: http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html instead of notepad.

Answer (score 1):

The `ZipFile.writestr` method writes files from Python string in binary mode. All text files added with this method must then have explicit `'\r\n'` line endings for Windows programs to read them correctly afterwards.

Your original content had 'universal line ending' within python, which usually only turn into CRLF (`'\r\n'`) when going through a text-mode output file.

That seems to be fixed in python 3.x